# Difference in heat output between IDE and SATA hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

Just a general question: is one supposed to produce more heat than the other? I took my HP DC7100 SFF desktop, swapped the 80 GB SATA for a 250 GB IDE HDD and the IDE drive temperature sensor seems to be less than the previous SATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generational differences in drive mechanics will predominate.

Anyway, the wattage should be printed on each drive.